# Make FAB not to be clipped inside bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-view, floating-action-button

i'm trying to overlap the bottom navigation bar with a FAB. I want my navigationbar to look like this:

[image: Desired result]

But instead it cuts off the button like so:

[image: current result]

How do I prevent the FAB from being cut off? Here's my XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mobgen.designsprintapp.ui.main.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_color_state"
            app:itemTextColor="@android:color/black"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation" >

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/tools"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                android:scaleType="center"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/play" />
            </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that you have explicitly specified width and heigh parameters of `FloatingActionButton`, whereas it cannot take any width/height. [`app:fabSize`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html#attr_android.support.design:fabSize) parameters specifies 3 sizes for the fab: auto, mini, and normal.

Leave `layout_width` and `layout_height` as `wrap_content`, and specify the desired fab size using `app:fabSize="normal"` (or other parameter from the list).

Additionally, make `BottomNavigationView`'s height `wrap_content`, because fab has some internal paddings.

---

In order to draw a child outside of the enclosing layout apply [`android:clipChildren="false"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:clipChildren) to the enclosing `ViewGroup`.

Comment: that doesn't really matter, I don't want the FAB to be completely inside the borders of the bottom nav view, but it has to slightly overlap the top as you can see on the image.

Comment: @Tim, if that's your requirement, then apply [`android:clipChildren="false"`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:clipChildren) to `BottomNavigationView`.

Comment: i had to apply android:clipChildren="false" to the linearlayout

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the button is **inside** the navigation bar. Move it outside, so it will fully visible and **over** the navigation bar.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_color_state"
            app:itemTextColor="@android:color/black"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation" >

            </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/tools"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                android:layout_anchor="@id/navigation"
                android:layout_anchorGravity="top|center"
                android:scaleType="center"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/play" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried that, but it just places the button below the menu bar

Comment: Oh, ops! Sorry, you need bot the items outside the `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

> Just add

```
 app:elevation="10dp"
```

> inside FloatingActionButton